# YouTube API - Retrieve results specific page

Tags: pagination, youtube-api

I'm trying to get paginated results from Youtube Data API v3,

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems?part=snippet&playlistId=UUCj956IF62FbT7Gouszaj9w&key={YOUR_API_KEY}
```

now, in the response there's the handy parameter nextPageToken that links to the next page of the results set

```
"nextPageToken": "CAUQAA"
```

Is there any way to jump to a specific page of the results, say the 6th?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apologies, but no, there is not. This is intentional. You can only move forward one page of results at a time.

Comment: Thank you, I had the feeling it was intentional, but can you tell me why? It's just curiosity, I'm sure there's a valid reason behind it

Comment: It leads to some efficiencies on the backend server—not sure that I can go into any more detail. Sorry.